# Navigation Menu and Transform not working

Tags: html, css, menu, css-transitions, transform

I am working on adding a fold out Navigation menu to my site and for some reason the Transform will not work, it will not work in my code editor (Espresso) nor will it work in Safari, comes up as unknown property. Not sure what I am missing in my code, it works beautiful in Chrome.

Below is my basic code:

```css
nav {
    background-color: #FDE74C;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),  opacity 0.55s ease;
  transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),opacity 0.55s ease;
 }

#menuToggle span:first-child {
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
 transform-origin: 0% 0%;

 }

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
-webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
 transform-origin: 0% 100%;

}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
   transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
   background: #232323;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);

  }

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
   transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);

 }

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #ededed;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-orgin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform:translate (-100%,0);
   transform: translate(-100%,0);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
   transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
   }

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
 opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Transformation does work, pls accept my edit so you can see the snippet, and see that it is right.

Comment: Hmm, does it work in Safari.... I must be missing something, I added browser prefix for the Transform and nothing

Answer (score 0):

```css
  
      nav {
     background-color: #FDE74C;
     padding:10px;
     padding-left: 0;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
    } 
    
    #menuToggle {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 50px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    #menuToggle input {
      display: block;
      width: 33px;
      height: 28px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0; /* hide this */
      z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
    }
    
    #menuToggle span {
      display: block;
      width: 33px;
      height: 4px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      position: relative;
      background: #cdcdcd;
      border-radius: 3px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 4px 0px;  
      transform-origin: 4px 0px;
      -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),  opacity 0.55s ease;  
      transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),opacity 0.55s ease;
     }
    
    #menuToggle span:first-child { 
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
     transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    
     }
    
    #menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) { 
    -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
     transform-origin: 0% 100%; 
    
    }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
       transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
       background: #232323;
    }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);  
      transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
      
      }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
       transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
    
     }
    
    #menu {
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
      padding: 50px;
      padding-top: 125px;
      background: #ededed;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
      transform-orgin: 0% 0%;
      -webkit-transform:translate (-100%,0);
       transform: translate(-100%,0);  
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
       transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);  
       }
    
    #menu li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);  
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
     opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
          <div id="menuToggle">
          <input type="checkbox">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <ul id="menu">
        <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Breeders </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
       </ul> 
      </div> 
     </nav>
```

```css
  
      nav {
     background-color: #FDE74C;
     padding:10px;
     padding-left: 0;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
    } 
    
    #menuToggle {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 50px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    #menuToggle input {
      display: block;
      width: 33px;
      height: 28px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0; /* hide this */
      z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
    }
    
    #menuToggle span {
      display: block;
      width: 33px;
      height: 4px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      position: relative;
      background: #cdcdcd;
      border-radius: 3px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 4px 0px;  
      transform-origin: 4px 0px;
      -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),  opacity 0.55s ease;  
      transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),opacity 0.55s ease;
     }
    
    #menuToggle span:first-child { 
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
     transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    
     }
    
    #menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) { 
    -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
     transform-origin: 0% 100%; 
    
    }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
       transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
       background: #232323;
    }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);  
      transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
      
      }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
       transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
    
     }
    
    #menu {
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
      padding: 50px;
      padding-top: 125px;
      background: #ededed;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
      transform-orgin: 0% 0%;
      -webkit-transform:translate (-100%,0);
       transform: translate(-100%,0);  
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
       transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);  
       }
    
    #menu li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);  
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
     opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
          <div id="menuToggle">
          <input type="checkbox">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <ul id="menu">
        <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Breeders </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
       </ul> 
      </div> 
     </nav>
```

```css
  
      nav {
     background-color: #FDE74C;
     padding:10px;
     padding-left: 0;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
    } 
    
    #menuToggle {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 50px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    #menuToggle input {
      display: block;
      width: 33px;
      height: 28px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0; /* hide this */
      z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
    }
    
    #menuToggle span {
      display: block;
      width: 33px;
      height: 4px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      position: relative;
      background: #cdcdcd;
      border-radius: 3px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 4px 0px;  
      transform-origin: 4px 0px;
      -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),  opacity 0.55s ease;  
      transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),opacity 0.55s ease;
     }
    
    #menuToggle span:first-child { 
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
     transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    
     }
    
    #menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) { 
    -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
     transform-origin: 0% 100%; 
    
    }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
       transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
       background: #232323;
    }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);  
      transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
      
      }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
       transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
    
     }
    
    #menu {
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
      padding: 50px;
      padding-top: 125px;
      background: #ededed;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
      transform-orgin: 0% 0%;
      -webkit-transform:translate (-100%,0);
       transform: translate(-100%,0);  
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
       transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);  
       }
    
    #menu li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);  
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
     opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
          <div id="menuToggle">
          <input type="checkbox">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <ul id="menu">
        <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Breeders </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
       </ul> 
      </div> 
     </nav>
```

```css
  
      nav {
     background-color: #FDE74C;
     padding:10px;
     padding-left: 0;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fbfbd4;
    } 
    
    #menuToggle {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 50px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    #menuToggle input {
      display: block;
      width: 33px;
      height: 28px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0; /* hide this */
      z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
    }
    
    #menuToggle span {
      display: block;
      width: 33px;
      height: 4px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      position: relative;
      background: #cdcdcd;
      border-radius: 3px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 4px 0px;  
      transform-origin: 4px 0px;
      -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),  opacity 0.55s ease;  
      transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),opacity 0.55s ease;
     }
    
    #menuToggle span:first-child { 
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
     transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    
     }
    
    #menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) { 
    -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
     transform-origin: 0% 100%; 
    
    }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
       transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
       background: #232323;
    }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);  
      transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
      
      }
    
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
       transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
    
     }
    
    #menu {
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
      padding: 50px;
      padding-top: 125px;
      background: #ededed;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
      transform-orgin: 0% 0%;
      -webkit-transform:translate (-100%,0);
       transform: translate(-100%,0);  
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
       transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);  
       }
    
    #menu li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    
    #menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);  
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
     opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
          <div id="menuToggle">
          <input type="checkbox">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <ul id="menu">
        <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Breeders </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
       </ul> 
      </div> 
     </nav>
```